# how to prevent push if there are unresolved conflicts using hook in git?

Tags: git, hook

i guess pre-receive hook may help.
i think

```
#!/bin/sh
read old_sha1 new_sha1 refname
git diff $old_sha1..$new_sha1 may
```

help to find out the conflict mark.
but how to use regex or other to judge if there is unresolved conflict in this commit?
conflicts are presented like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Conflict resolution is hard;
let's go shopping.
=======
Git makes conflict resolution easy.
>>>>>>> d7785deagea4342532g2q632y321632g23h23
```

Answer (score 9):

```
#!/bin/bash
read old_sha new_sha refname
if git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -qE '^[+]?(<<<<<|>>>>>)'; then
    echo "Saw a conflict marker in $(basename "$refname")."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why diff `$old_sha` and `$new_sha`? Why not simply `git show $new_sha`? Also, you might want to use the beginning of line marker `^` in your regular expression.

Comment: @DanielBaulig Because `pre-receive` is called once per push, not once per commit. A series of commits might all be pushed at once, in which case using `show` would only get the diff of the last commit, not all of the pushed commits.

Comment: Thank you for your example script. It did not work out of the box for me, since git diff would put '+' in front of the new lines. The regular expression without '^' worked.

Comment: @Ozan Updated to include an optional leading `+`. Thanks!

Comment: @Amber probably a backslash got lost, the regexp you passed to grep will match `>>>>>` appearing anywhere in the line (because the `?` applies to the `^+` regexp which means `^` repeated 1 or more times, basically making the `^` anchor optional). A correct regexp is `^\+?(<<<<<|>>>>>)` or `^[+]?(<<<<<|>>>>>)` (this avoids backslashes which might be swallowed when formatting this snippet in various forums).